# Where is the type conversion error in my Ruby code and is this the correct way to merge lists?

Tags: ruby

```
def merge_lists(list1, list2)
  mrg = []
  if list1[0] < list2[0]
    mrg += list1
  end
  mrg += list2
  return mrg
end

merge_lists("hijkl", "mnopq")
```

I keep getting a `no implicit conversion of String into Array`. Also, is this the correct way to combine two lists in Ruby if you want them to be sorted? I'm a little confused by the potency of Ruby.

Comment: Well, for one, you're trying to treat two strings as lists, which is why you're getting the implicit conversion error.

Answer (score 1):

As Brandon Anzaldi mentioned, you're attempting to merge strings, not arrays.

A simple way to merge lists is to use the [union operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-7C) which will combine and remove the duplicate elements, and then call `sort`:

```
def merge_lists(list1, list2)
  (list1 | list2).sort
end

alpha = %w(a b c d e f g) # shorthand syntax for creating arrays
bet   = %w(h i j k l m n)
merge_lists(alpha, bet) # => %w(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n)
```

As for the "correct way to sort" it really depends on what you're sorting lists of, and how much you care about performance. I believe your use case means that the built in `sort` method on array will be plenty fine; however, you can always implement your own algorithm.